# I do not get an answer from module.exports

Tags: javascript

db.js

```
 pool.connect(function (err, client, done) {

client.query('SELECT id, user_id, name  FROM public.chat;', function (err, 
 result) {
    if (err) console.log("error" + err.message);


    else {
        module.exports.res = result.rows[0];
         }
        });

 });
```

file app.js

```
 var con = require('./db/connect');

 console.log(con.res);
```

I'm getting the result undefined
,I don't understand, the reason is callback?

Comment: *"the reason is callback"* Basically yes. Instead your module should export a function which performs the query, and the caller can provide a callback. Look into promises as well.

Comment: That's right, in this situation you need to make a promise, after which I get the data I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

**db.js:**

```
module.exports = pool.connect(function (err, client, done) {
                   client.query('SELECT id, user_id, name  FROM public.chat;', function (err, result) {

                     if (err) 
                       console.log("error" + err.message);
                     else 
                       return result.rows[0];
                     });
                  });
```

**app.js:**

```
 var con = require('./db/connect');
 console.log(con());
```